# c# ¿Cual es la mejor manera de enviar imagenes continuamente por socket tcp?

Tags: c#, socket, aforge

estoy usando AForge mas en especifico la seccion de video la clase ScreenCaptureStream para obtener el bitmap de la pantalla del ordenador para posteriormente, mandar esa imagen a un servidor el cual mostrara las imagenes como si fuera un video.

Perp el problema es que al mostrar la secuencia de imagenes en el formulario del servidor es lento, teniendo aproximadamente un segundo de diferencia para cambiar la imagen, por lo que mi duda es, cual seria la mejor manera de realizar una suerte de streaming?

Codigo del servidor:

```
TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(client.GetStream());

                int size = reader.ReadInt32();

                //GZipStream stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes(size)), CompressionMode.Decompress);
                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes(size));
                //stream.CopyTo(ms);

                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);

                client.Close();
```

Codigo del cliente:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            //MemoryStream compress = new MemoryStream();

            //GZipStream gZipStream = new GZipStream(compress, CompressionMode.Compress);

            eventArgs.Frame.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            byte[] data = ms.GetBuffer();
            //gZipStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            //data = compress.ToArray();

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(localAddr, port));

            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(client.GetStream());

            writer.Write(data.Length);
            writer.Write(data);

            writer.Close();
            client.Close();
```

Comment: winforms? wpf? probablemente el problema es como mostrar las cosas en la pantalla.

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!